# Written lyrics different from the song - Listening issue

Tags: pronunciation, song-lyrics

I just listened to the new Tani Yuuki song 燦々たるや. All the lyrics I found online say:

> 固く締め過ぎないように
> 緩んで解けてしまわぬように
> 心と心の奥の方に
> そっと愛の錠をかける行為

However... what I hear is:

> 固く締め過ぎないように
> 緩んで**を解けてしまる**ように
> 心と心の**僕**の方に
> そっと愛の錠をかける行為

Which one is correct? Is he saying 緩んで解けてしまわぬように or 緩んでを解けてしまるように? And then 心と心の奥の方に (which I guess makes more sense) or 心と心の僕の方に?

And then again... The lyrics online say:

> 僕を信じてくれるのなら
> 君が信じてくれるのなら
> 常識だって壊してやるさ
> 傍だって変えられるさ
> 僕の声が届いてるなら
> 叫んで、助けに来て

But what I hear is:

> 僕を信じてくれるのなら
> 君が信じてくれるのなら
> 常識だって壊してやるさ
> **ことわり**だって変えられるさ
> 僕の声が届いてるなら
> 叫んで、助けに来て

Is he saying 傍だって変えられるさ or ことわりだって変えられるさ? And in this case... would it be 理りだって変えられるさ or 断りだって変えられるさ? I think 理り would make more sense here, but I am not sure...

This is the link to the song on youtube for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puZ4gdj1OD0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **解けてしまわぬ**: It's pronounced ほどけてしまわぬ (although his pronunciation of わ here is not very clear). 解ける can be read in two ways, and here it's not [とける](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B) but [ほどける](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-1). (Besides, をとけてしまる is simply ungrammatical.)
- **心と心の奥**: This indeed sounds closer to ぼく to me, but I think it's merely a mispronunciation. (Meaning-wise, 心の僕 makes little sense, while 心の奥 makes perfect sense.)
- **傍**: He is clearly saying ことわり, and it should mean "reason/nature" (usually written as 理 in kanji). ことわり is not a common reading of the kanji 傍, but [creative reading](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/creative-furigana/info) is very common in lyrics. (One of the common readings of 傍 is かたわら, but this makes no sense in this context.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it makes sense! I am glad I at least heard it correctly! Still so much to learn! You have been very helpful!